# Creating a dynamic Leaderboard with points

Tags: javascript, database, leaderboard

Im new to programming with JavaScript and Need some help of you guys. What im trying to do:

Create a leaderboard depending on Points of the user.

The Points are acquired in 3 different disciplines. Users can enter their discipline and their result for each discipline. Then the users get Points according to their ranking against other users in their discipline based on the result provided.

e.g.: Discipline 1, rank 1 = 25pts, Discipline 1 rank 2 = 18pts, Discipline 2, rank 1 = 25pts and so on. But I want to create a Leaderboard containing all Points gathered of all 3 disciplines per user. So all the Points a user got in all disciplines have to be added for the final Leaderboard.

User1 Overall Points = Discipline1 Points + Discipline 2 Points + Discipline 3 Points

Leaderboard:

User1 -> Most Overall Points

User2 -> 2nd most Overall Points

User3 -> 3rd most Overall Points

I dont Need any help on Building the UI for the users to enter their data but on how to compare the user results, add the Points to the users and then Combine the data into one leaderboard.

I would try to work with a table per discipline where all users + their results are gathered and a 2nd table where I define which rank gets which amount of Points.

Any advice on how to go on About it is much appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Edit:

Here my Code so far:

```
//define input tables

//define pointstable inputs
var points_rank1 = 25;
var points_rank2 = 20;
var points_rank3 = 15;
var points_rank4 = 10;

let pointstable = [points_rank1, points_rank2, points_rank3, points_rank4];

//define user inputs
var username1 = "user1";
var username2 = "user2";
var username3 = "user3";
var username4 = "user4";

var reps_user1 = 12;
var reps_user2 = 14;
var reps_user3 = 11;
var reps_user4 = 13;

var workoutid_user1 = 1;
var workoutid_user2 = 1;
var workoutid_user3 = 1;
var workoutid_user4 = 1;



//build array for workout 1
let workoutprofiles = [];

let workoutprofile1 = {};
workoutprofile1.id = 1;
workoutprofile1.name = username1;
workoutprofile1.reps = reps_user1;
workoutprofile1.workout = workoutid_user1;
workoutprofile1.points = 0;
workoutprofiles.push(workoutprofile1)

let workoutprofile2 = {};
workoutprofile1.id = 2;
workoutprofile2.name = username2;
workoutprofile2.reps = reps_user2;
workoutprofile2.workout = workoutid_user2;
workoutprofile2.points = 0;
workoutprofiles.push(workoutprofile2)

let workoutprofile3 = {};
workoutprofile1.id = 3;
workoutprofile3.name = username3;
workoutprofile3.reps = reps_user3;
workoutprofile3.workout = workoutid_user3;
workoutprofile3.points = 0;
workoutprofiles.push(workoutprofile3)

let workoutprofile4 = {};
workoutprofile1.id = 4;
workoutprofile4.name = username4;
workoutprofile4.reps = reps_user4;
workoutprofile4.workout = workoutid_user4;
workoutprofile4.points = 0;
workoutprofiles.push(workoutprofile4)

//sort workoutprofiles by reps
workoutprofiles.sort(function(a,b) {
    return b.reps-a.reps;
})

//fill profiles with points
workoutprofiles.forEach(function(entry){
    id = entry.id
    entry.points = pointstable[id];
})
```

The workoutprofile Points stay undefined and I dont really know why…

Comment: Start by posting your initial code.  The best way to lean to code is to wrestle with the concepts and learn how to debug.

Comment: If you find yourself duplicating a lot of very similar code, be highly suspicious that there's a better way. I took the liberty of optimising your code. https://jsfiddle.net/1ow5vbL6/

Comment: Thanks Utkanos! Way better that way ( I struggle to understand the map/obj Syntax though…) 

Any suggestions on how to handle multiple Workouts with different reps but same users? Giving them Points again for an Overall Points table? Also if the usernames are the same but the Input order or order of Arrays differs from Workout to Workout. That's giving me headaches already…

Comment: You're welcome. I can't comment too much on your specific scenario, at least without investing significant time understanding your business logic, but I was just trying to show you general means of avoiding duplication. You can often make great savings by utilising arrays/objects and then loops rather than duplicative, procedural code. Map generates a new array from an existing one, incidentally.